# how do I see which user I am logged in as in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, login, user

I have multiple text console session open and log in as different users into different consoles. I forget after while which consoles belong to which user, it would be nice to not have to quit and log back in.

How do I see which user I am logged in as?

Is there a way to change which user I logged in as with out logging out?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Actually, you need to use two functions

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

[CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

Sometimes, they are different

Comment: eg. if you login to mysql via `mysql -ulalala` where `lalala` user doesn't exist, you will be allowed to login as 'anonymous' mysql user, namely `''@'localhost'`. In this case returns of functions would be  `USER()= lalala@localhost` and `CURRENT_USER() = @localhost`

Comment: @DimitryK When that happens, you can run `SHOW GRANTS;` to see what permissions you have. Even if you see nothing except `USAGE`, you still need to be aware that certain test databases are 100% accessible to an anonymous user. See my post `MySQL : Why are there “test” entries in mysql.db?` (http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13361/877)

Comment: +1 for `SHOW GRANTS`, strange that I haven't stumbled upon it though reading numerous Mysql Tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [user() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user)

> select user();
>   Will show you which user is logged in.

Comment: Does that link still work for you? I decided to link to google's cache because of the mysql -> oracle breakage.

Comment: It does work, it has an other interesting function as well  
 select database(); 
will show you your currently selected database.

Comment: That's really annoying, I wonder why it doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @pricechild http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user

Comment: Nope, sends me to http://search.oracle.com/search/search?q=information-functions.html&group=MySQL#function_user

Comment: @pricechild which browser are you using. I use google chrome it works perfectly. I wander where the redirection is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'status':

> MariaDB [my_database]> status
>
> Current user:      root@localhost

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
select user();
```

work?

I pinched it from [the 3rd google result for 'mysql whoami':](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KS0MmMWHwD4J:lists.mysql.com/mysql/110816%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a&source=encrypted.google.com)