# Connecting mysql via 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Tags: macos, mysql

I connected mysql on Mac OS X using this command:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

After I logged in, I fired up this command:

```
select user();
```

and it showed:

```
 root@localhost
```

and even wired, I already change the root password on 127.0.0.1 via `SET PASSWORD` command.

When I typed in

```
show grants for 'root'@'127.0.0.1';
```

the password did change in the result.

However, I still have to use the old password to log in with the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

### QUESTIONS

- Could you tell me why this happened?
- Is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting to MySQL using 127.0.0.1 requires the TCP/IP protocol.

The problem is that the mysql client tries to outsmart you by saying

- If you specify 127.0.0.1 and do not tell me the protocol, I will use the socket and behave like a localhost connection.
- If you specify 127.0.0.1 and tell me to use TCP/IP, THEN I will use a TCP/IP connection

In light of this, you must connect as follows:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp
```

to verify this, please run this after connecting

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

Both should say `root@127.0.0.1` ([how do I see which user I am logged in as in MySQL?](https://superuser.com/questions/266758/how-do-i-see-which-user-i-am-logged-in-as-in-mysql/271516#271516))

Give it a Try !!!