# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) [despite commenting out bind-address & skip-networking]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, mysql-workbench

Okay, so disclaimer: I'm an absolute mysql noob. Gimme any other development type area and I'm fine.

So, I just started using Ubuntu 12.04 an setup mysql. Never really used localhost since we have a staging environment at work that I usually access.
However, a client had a really large DB dump that I needed to access and I didn't want to put in on the server for everyone to deal with so I tried to use localhost

Whenever I try to access it through MySQL Workbench I get an error so I had a look at a couple of articles online and tried a couple of different things but if I run the following command in the terminal, I get an error:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

Produces the following

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

However, if I access mysql like so:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then enter my password, I can access mysql fine.

Here's what

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

contains at the moment (I've tried looking for other versions of this file). I've left out all the commented out bits for brevity's sake.

```
[client] 
port            = 3306 
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe] 
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql 
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr 
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql 
tmpdir          = /tmp 
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql 
skip-external-locking

key_buffer              = 16M 
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K 
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP

query_cache_limit       = 1M 
query_cache_size        = 16M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days        = 10 
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump] 
quick quote-names 
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk] key_buffer              = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Can you add the full command line of the running `mysqld` process, and the output of `netstat -anp | grep 3306`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log into mysql with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

please run this command

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

[CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

I have discussed this before : [how do I see which user I am logged in as in MySQL?](https://superuser.com/questions/266758/how-do-i-see-which-user-i-am-logged-in-as-in-mysql/271516#271516)

In your case, my guess would be that [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) is `'root'@'localhost'`.

There are two things you need to connect to MySQL using `127.0.0.1`:

- You need the user `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` defined. That's probably what [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) said.
- You need to explicit use the TCP/IP protocol

To create the user, login to MySQL and run `SHOW GRANTS;`

Whatever comes backup, copy and paste it into an editor, replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`, command the edited command into mysql and execute it.

Now, to login using TCP/IP do this:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp
```

Once you login, run `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and you will see something different.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Great answer. I'm not sure it's working @ 100% at the moment but I'm sure it will. I just don't have the time to check right now. I will post back. Gave you the up vote because of your detail. Nice!!

Answer (score 0):

check whether mysql server is running, configured firewall allowing mysql server port.check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) also

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) and check your firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to connect to a remote mysql db.

I fixed it by opening the firewall on the db server to allow traffic through:

```
sudo ufw allow mysql
```